# How to add empty div using PHP

Tags: php

I have 27 records on three pages in PHP. On each page I add an empty `<div>` in cross direction as it can be seen on the image below.

[image]

```
$keys = 1;
foreach ($fetrecords as $recVals) {
    if ($keys == 3 || $keys == 5 || $keys == 7) {    
        echo '<div id = "emptydiv">test</div>';
    } else {    
        echo '<div id = "mainarticles">code</div>';
    }

    $keys++;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: its dont display 3,5 and 7 record @u_mulder

Comment: Remove `else` and output `code` always.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$keys=1;

foreach($fetrecords as $recVals):

    if($keys == 3 || $keys == 5 || $keys == 7):
        echo '<div id="emptydiv">test</div>';
    else :
        echo '<div id="mainarticles">code</div>';
    endif

    $keys++;

    if($keys == 8)
        $keys = 1;

endforeach;
?>
```

as i think your desire output for all 3 pages.

Comment: its nearly correct answer but 3,5,7 records can't display